# Premier Pro "Bend" effect control values changing by themselves?

Tags: premiere

I'm still pretty new to Premier Pro (up to date) so maybe I'm overlooking some type of logic but is it normal for effect values to change sometimes when hitting enter? Using the slider I can't select certain values either sometimes it'll nudge 1 unit over to the left or right. I was using another effect that did this too.

eg; changing Horizontal Intensity from 100 to 12 made it 13 while also changing the value of like every other one o_o

[image: Effect Controls > Bend >>> Values changing after hitting enter]

Comment: I don't have a Bend plugin in Mac Premiere Pro CC 2021. Is it a built-in plugin, and are you using Premiere Pro on Windows?  My best guess would be that changing some values causes others to need to adjust slightly, which causes the values to round up or down to the nearest value.

Comment: @tomh I am using Premier Pro for Windows. I did receive an answer on plebbit from a helpful user named "smushkan" that I will share here though.

It's normal with that particular effect (and possibly a few others.)

That effect uses a 5-bit unsigned integer for the 'intensity' parameters, meaning you're not actually controlling it on a scale of 0-100 (which would require 7 bits), but instead on a scale of 0-31.

Premiere's effect control sliders can only show 0-100, so it converts that 0-31 value into the closest valid value on a 0-100 scale.

Comment: In practice that means the only valid values you'll get are:

    0

    3.33...

    6.66...

    10

    13.33...

    16.66...

    20

... and so on all the way to 100, totalling 31 different options (and the numbers get rounded down/up to on the slider too.)

One of the weird quicks of some of the older effects in Premiere - that particular effect has been round since at least CS5 so it's over a decade old!

Comment: You should add this as an answer - you can answer your own questions on here